# VisualSVN pre-commit rule

Tags: svn, batch-file, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

Using this hook with VisualSVN Server, added to the Repository/hooks folder as pre-commit.bat.

My question is how do I add the rule that a comment must always start with a numeric value? I want the first part of the comment to always be the issue number from a bug tracker. Eg. "123 - this commit fixes issue 123"

```
@echo off
::    
:: Stops commits that have empty log messages.
::

@echo off

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the path to the repository and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

rem check for an empty log message
svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0

:err
echo. 1>&2
echo Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message 1>&2
echo Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and 1>&2
echo then try committing again. -- Thank you 1>&2
exit 1
```

Comment: About numbers in comments: the revision number, when someone add a comment, doesn't match your requirements?

Comment: the number would be the issue number from a bug tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regular expression:

```
findstr "^[0-9]"
```

I.e.

```
svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr "^[0-9] > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

See the article [KB140: Validating commit log messages in VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00140/) and use the option `--regexp ARG`. In your case when you want the commit log message to always start with a numeric value, try the `\d+` regexp value.

E.g., like this:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks" check-logmessage ^
  --regexp "\d+" ^
  -t "%2" "%1"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Issue number must be specified. >&2 & exit /b 1
```