# Empty Repos-Path/Txn-Name in VisualSvn

Tags: svn, batch-file, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks, pre-commit

I am trying to set up a simple pre-commit hook script that rejects commits without a message. We use VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 and I have added a pre-commit hook that points to a .bat file.

The file is executed, but the parameters for REPOS-PATH and TXN-Name are empty. In my script I have tried logging %0 to a file, and i see that this is only returning the path to the script. So for some reason VisualSVN Server does not pass these parameters. What could be wrong?

The code for the test:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

set SVNLOOK="%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"


echo "repos %REPOS%." >> C:\Repositories\Hooks\test.log
echo "txn %TXN%." >> C:\Repositories\Hooks\test.log

exit 0
```

After a commit, test.log contains:

> "repos ."
>
> "txn ."

Comment: Please show the code of your hook script.

Comment: This pre-commit hook script works on my machine. Are you able to run other hook scripts?

Comment: Start the batch file with `echo %1 %2 &pause` to see where the problem lies, as the batch file does log correctly passed values for me. If the values aren't getting into the batch in the first place, there's no point concentrating on the .bat .... also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920189/visualsvn-pre-commit-rule

Comment: Plenty of info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247888/how-to-require-commit-messages-in-visualsvn-server

Comment: As i wrote, i have tried outputting these values and also %0. These values do not get into the script. I have also looked plenty on the page linked to - but this page does not mention anything about my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hook scripts execute in an empty environment - no variables are set, not `%PATH%`, not `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%`. You need to specify the **full path** to `svnlook.exe` without depending upon an environment variable that hasn't been defined in your script.

For the missing `%REPOS%` and `%TXN%`, I use the following in my hooks:

```
set "REPOS=%~1"
set "TXN=%~2"
```

Comment: I doubt that your answer is correct. No env. variables get removed, in fact.

Comment: Hooks definitely *are* executed in an environment devoid of any pre-set environment variables, [per the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

Comment: I tried using set "REPOS=%~1" and set "TXN=%~2" instead. This makes no difference

Comment: @alroc the manual is wrong on this point. On Windows no env variables get removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VisualSVNServerHooks.exe check-logmessage` pre-commit hook that comes with modern VisualSVN Server versions and is located in the `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin` directory. This simple tool will help you define the minimum allowed number of characters in the log message.

See the article [KB140: Validating commit log messages in VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00140/) for instructions.